# Session is not storing variable PHP

Tags: php, session

I have started `session` in the `header.php` and included in all files but when I declare a variable like `$_SESSION['var_name']="Hello";` and get it on other file like `echo $_SESSION['var_name'];` and I have my `php.ini` in the folder which contains

```
session.save_path = "C:\Xampp\tmp"
```

But it's return `null` & when i use `print_r($_SESSION);` it's return `array( )`. I removed `php.ini` file and restart the xampp server but didn't get any thing.

Comment: did you use `session_start();` at the begining of each php files in your `header.php` ?

Comment: I used `session_start()` in `header.php` and include the `header.php` in each file.

Comment: How many `.ini` files in your folder

Comment: Yes I have another file named `.user.ini` but the content is same as `php.ini`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your contribution but I found the solution
I created `.htaccess` and put content

```
<IfModule php7_module>
  session.save_path = "C:\Xampp\tmp"
</IfModule>
```

And that works for me
And my other `.ini` file are containing

```
session.save_path = "C:\Xampp\tmp"
```